# Illegal pream-token error

Tags: errors, longtable

I'm facing an error while compiling and have already included the necessary packages. O want the three columns to be 15 % 70 % 15% respectively and the first two left aligned with the third right aligned. However, I'm facing issues compiling and checked other error troubleshoots but those solutions didn't work.

```
Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (1): `c' used. ...extwidth} 1{.7\textwidth} r{.15\textwidth}}
```

```latex
\begin{longtable}[h]{l{.15\textwidth} l{.7\textwidth} r{.15\textwidth}} 
        \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Units} \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: `l`, `c`, and `r` don't take arguments like that. You should use `p`.

Comment: `[h]` has nothing to do in a `longtable`, as it is not a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are interested in using the `W{<alignment>}{<width>}` column type that was recently introduced in the `array` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{W{l}{.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} W{l}{.7\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} W{r}{.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}} 
        \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Units} \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Please also keep in mind that I have also changed the widths of the columns as currently the table is still wider than the text width. This is due to the tabcolsep that is responsible for some horizontal white space on both sides of a cell. In order make the table as wide as the text width, I have used the `calc` package and used widths like `0.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was struggling with setting up the long table.